# Tri-mensional array looping

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I'm really stuck at a certain point in my project. I'm trying to convert a two-dimensional array into a three-dimensional array. Currently I´m at this point:

```
array (size=4)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string 'foo' (length=3)
      1 => string 'a' (length=0)
      2 => string 'b' (length=0)
      3 => string '0' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string 'bar' (length=3)
      1 => string 'a' (length=0)
      2 => string 'b' (length=0)
      3 => string '1' (length=1)
  2 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string 'bas' (length=3)
      1 => string 'a' (length=0)
      2 => string 'b' (length=0)
      3 => string '1' (length=1)
  3 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string 'tas' (length=3)
      1 => string 'a' (length=0)
      2 => string 'b' (length=0)
      3 => string '0' (length=1)
```

What I would like to do is make a new array with key values of array[ ][3] (I hope this makes any sense) so something like this:

```
array (size=2)
    0 => array (size=2)
        0 => array (size=2)
                   0 => string 'foo' (length=3)
                   1 => string 'a' (length=0)
                   2 => string 'b' (length=0)
        1 => array (size=2)
                   0 => string 'tas' (length=3)
                   1 => string 'a' (length=0)
                   2 => string 'b' (length=0)
    1 => array (size=2)
        0 => array (size=2)
                   0 => string 'bar' (length=3)
                   1 => string 'a' (length=0)
                   2 => string 'b' (length=0)
        1 => array (size=2)
                   0 => string 'bas' (length=3)
                   1 => string 'a' (length=0)
                   2 => string 'b' (length=0)
```

Right now this is the best way I can explain it, I'm not sure if I make any sense or if this is even possible, but if anyone could shed a light on this it would be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance,

Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array = array();
$array[] = array('foo','foo','foo',1);
$array[] = array('a','a','a',1);
$array[] = array('b','a','a',0);
$array[] = array('c','a','a',0);
$new_array =group_by_sub_array_key($array,3);
print_r($new_array);


function group_by_sub_array_key($array,$kn){
$new_array = array();
foreach($array AS $v){
    $key=$v[$kn];
    if(!array_key_exists($v[$kn],$new_array)){
    $new_array[$key]=array();
    }
    unset($v[$kn]);
    $new_array[$key][] = $v;
}

return $new_array;
}
```